# Match Strings with optional data

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to match the following two `String` objects with a regular expression. I am grouping and pulling out the values 3.00, 4.00, 100.00 from the first `String`; it works fine. However, I have a lot of `String` objects, and not all contain the third group, so I want to leave that group as optional. Thus I added a `?` for that group to make it optional. Yet it doesn't make a difference, and any `String` without the third group portion is not matched by my regular expression.

How I can make the third group optional? And is there any advice as to whether or not my regular expression could be formatted better? Thank you!

**Regular Expression**

```
cost{"([0-9]+\.[0-9]+)[0-9"{]},+[a-zA-Z0-9]+{"+([0-9]+\.[0-9]+)[0-9A-Za-z"},{[\]\._-]+:price{"([0-9]+\.[0-9]+)?
```

**String 1 which matches since it has third group values**

```
cost{"3.00{},asdjdfhjkf23hawoutcome{"4.00"},79234gh3k2bdfsfgs2323g23jkg23{[]._-,bonus:price{"100.00"}jksdfjksdf222sdcfszfSDAWFD;
```

**String 2 which doesn't match because it doesn't have third group values**

```
cost{"5.00{},asdjdfhjkf23hawoutcome{"36.00"},79234gh3k2bdfsfgs2323g23jkg23{[]._-,jksdfjksdf222sdcfszfSDAWFD;
```

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew The String is exactly as these String varing in figures and may or may not have group 3. File size wise it is over 1TB if that matters.

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/cY3oH8/1. The POI is `(?::price{"([0-9]+\.[0-9]+))?`, this non-capturing group is totally optional.

Comment: What, exactly, is "group 3"?

Comment: @QPaysTaxes The value 100.00 in String 1

Comment: @JasSy Are you sure that's what you want to be optional? In your second string, that's not there, but neither is `price:`.

Comment: Also, [related and possibly duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22937618/1863564), though I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to wrap *all* of group 3 in parentheses to make this work. I'm not sure exactly what you mean by it, but just going on what they contain, this is how your regex should look:

```
cost{"([0-9]+\.[0-9]+)[0-9"{]},+[a-zA-Z0-9]+{"+([0-9]+\.[0-9]+)[0-9A-Za-z"},{[\]\._-]+(:price{"([0-9]+\.[0-9]+))?
```

Notice the `()` around the last bit -- that's what makes the regex treat the whole thing as a single unit. Otherwise, it just looks at the last logical piece and sees the last `()`, not all of the part you want ignored.